# How can I share a folder on VirtualBox?

Tags: linux, windows-10, linux-terminal

I want to share a folder between Windows 10 and VirtualBox (CentOS OS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to jalbarl's answer, which gives the typical method of doing this in Virtual Box, you could try and somewhat more generic approach and just connect your CentOS VM to a file share you create on your Windows machine.

[Here's a link to CentOS instructions](https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/WindowsShares) for doing this.

The key steps are:

1. `yum install samba-client samba-common cifs-utils`
2. `mkdir /mnt/win` (or create some other directory to mount the share to)
3. Add this to your */etc/fstab*: `\\winbox\getme /mnt/win cifs user,uid=500,rw,suid,username=sushi,password=yummy 0 0` (alter it accordingly, you may need to replace '*winbox*' with the IP of your Windows machine)
4. Mount the share: `mount /mnt/win`

Note the link above where these steps came from has more secure and alternative methods explained as well.

This approach has the merit of not depending on Virtual Box's addons, which are fine, but if you move your VM to other platforms (VMware, for example), you may find you like this more generic approach

Answer (score 2):

Install the Guest Additions in CentOS (Devices->Insert GA CD image, then navigate to the CD ROM and run the installer). Once these are installed, you can go into the Settings menu of this VM, choose "Shared Folders" and add as many folders as you like (also select auto-mount if you don't want to mount them manually). CentOS reboots are needed after every operation (GA installation and adding new folders).